# How to do a custom JoptionPane

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, dialog, joptionpane

I need to do a JOptionPane (or something similar) with a JTextField and two RadioButtons but I don't know if that's possible. I have a main frame with differents options and when I click on "Operacion" I should call the dialog. How can I make that dialog?

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: Use a class that extends JDialog. Set it to modal with .setModal(true) then show it to the user. You can design its init method to build it anyway you like, and it will behave just like a JOptionPane, assuming you expose something like a .getDialogResult(), which returns true/false depending on what they clicked, and a .getValue() which returns the user input data.

Answer (score 4):

A textfield and two radio buttons should be small enough to fit into a JOptionPane, so perhaps it's best to keep using that.

Add the JTextField with the two radio buttons to a JPanel, and add that JPanel as the component that's displayed in a JOptionPane. Probably want to use the option pane that displays just an "Ok", with one of the radio buttons already selected.

To be safe, you may want to wrap that JPanel in a JScrollPane because I don't think JOptionPanes are re-sizable and depending on if a user changes your look and feel through command line options or perhaps accessibility settings then you might cut off some GUI components from them.

Comment: scroll pane shouldn't be necessary - the components listed should `pack()` fine (which `JOptionPane` does for you each time it's shown)

Comment: FYI: with a bit of juggling `JOptionPane` can be made resizable: `op = new JOptionPane(...)`, `dlg = op.createDialog();` `dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` and finally: `dlg.setResizable(true);` `dlg.pack();`

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm not a fan of using the JOptionPane for this. Go down the path of using JDialog.

It can be as simple as:

```
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        // Add components and listeners here

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.add(innerPanel);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e)
            {
                super.windowClosing(e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I add a JDialog in my project and I configure it but I don't know how to call the JDialog from the JFrame and I need to pass a variable from the frame to the dialog. I'm using Eclipse with Window Builder plugin and it creates one class for each component in the package. I think I'm not explaining well.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Window Builder. Hopefully it has a way of inserting your own custom logic. Within the JFrame custom logic you need to create your Dialog. Something like `MyJDialog mydiaolog = new MyJDialog();`

Comment: Ok, I try it. I'm doing all automatic with the interface. I will do the dialog and copy the code. Thank you guy.